# Regex in Jersey Path Annotation

Tags: java, regex, path, jersey

I'm currently facing a simple idea with a API that looks like this:

```
/users                  -> return a collection of users
/users/1                -> return all data included in one user
/users/1/information    -> return the information json
/users/1/dogs/rex       -> return the information of the users dog rex :)
/users/1/dogs/          -> return the collection of the users dogs
```

Note these represent a folderstructure in a file system where users, 1, dogs, rex are folders and information would be file including a json (doesn't really matter what is in it)

So my idea was building this with a regex (why?! I want to make this a little generic - all I'm doing here is only "a little figment").

```
1 Folder:            \/[a-zA-Z0-9]+
2 Folders:           \/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+
2 Folders - 1 File:  \/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+
4 Folders:           \/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+ //should be the first loop of 2 folders.
```

So how do I get a regex does also match a loop (i know `2 Folders *3 -> 6 Folders)` and `(2 Folders + 1 File)*2 -> 6 "Folders")` but at this point it doesn't really matter for me.

Comment: What do you mean by `2 Folders *3 -> 6 Folders`? How are 'folders' related to 'users' and 'dogs'?

Comment: have a look at the first sentence after the description of what ever path represent :) I want to do a "loop" in the regex and the regex for 2 Folders would also be matched with 3 folders

Comment: I've read your question. Can you answer the second question in my comment?

Comment: users is a folder, 1 is a folder and also dogs is a folder.

Comment: oh damed - i deleted a row of the explanation sorry! -> added it now :)

Comment: How deep does this folder structure go? Are there any fixed levels at the start of such a path?

Comment: thats the think i don't want to make the depth of the folder structure fixed so these could go also with 12 folders or more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58815/discussion-between-tichodroma-and-domi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to model folders and files and their relationship, I propose a different approach. It is not necassary to duplicate the file/folder relationshipt in the URLs. Such information can be part of the representation of each file/folder resource.

### The Resources

#### Files

A File has an ID, a name, and possibly some other properties. It is *contained* in a folder.

```
{
  "id": "file-1",
  "link": "/files/file-1",
  "name": "file-1.txt",
  "folder": "folder-1"
}
```

The collection resource of *all* files has the URL

```
/files
```

A single file has the URL

```
/files/{id}
```

for example

```
/files/file-1
```

#### Folders

A folder has an ID, a name, and possibly some other properties. It *contains* zero or more files and folders.

```
{
  "id": "folder-1",
  "link": "/folders/folder-1",
  "name": "folder-1",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": "folder-2",
      "link": "/folders/folder-2"
    },
    {
      "id": "file-1"
      "link": "/files/file-1"
    }
  ]
}
```

The collection resource of *all* folders has the URL

```
/folders
```

A single folder has the URL

```
/folders/{id}
```

for example

```
/folders/folder-1
```

#### The Root Folder

The root folder has some known ID, for examle

```
/folders/root
```

Comment: okay I will have to think about this - i will be back soon. thanks at the moment - it looks like it is what i want to do so +1 for now :)

Comment: For me this solution won't work - I was talking with some of my co-workers and now we came to the conclusion that we wan't look at the file content and don't want to have any requierements on these. Of course you answer is valid for my question because it represents the folder with relationships in files so i will accept this answer. Thanks for your help and the idea - I think i will come back really soon because it would be a nice feature to solve problems with this technique :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't what you wanted but rather than try and shoe-horn your solution into regex, why don't you capture the whole path with `@PathParam` and parse it out in java?

```
@Path("/operation/{path:.+}")
public String getFile(@PathParam("path") String path) {
    // Parse "path"
}
```

The path parameter shown should capture everything after the **/operation/** in the rest call.

Comment: I came to the same idea but i only want to allow non special charakters so {path : ([a-zA-Z0-9\\/]+)} would be my regex and i also don't want the operation in my path so I also skipped it:  @Path("{path : ([a-zA-Z0-9\\/]+)}")